# How to print pdf file with bluetooth in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Can anyone knows how to print a pdf file via bluetooth printing?

I know how to print pdf file using wifi or IP Address but I have to print with bluetooth printer, not with a wifi printer.

Printing PDF file using bluetooth

Comment: Does the printer support PDF?  Not every printer is the same.  Most portable Bluetooth printers use thermal paper and do not support hi res

Comment: @Jason, I am going to use TSC Or Zebra Mobile Printer. So I guess yes, those printers support PDF.

Comment: A good first step would be to read the documentation for the specific model you’re using